# Intersect a set with a list of sets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have a set `s` and a list of set `l` as below.

```
s = {1,2,3,4}
l = [{1}, {1,2,3}, {3}]
```

The output should be

```
out = [{1}, {1,2,3}, {3}]
```

I am using the following code to accomplish it. But I was hoping there would be a faster way? Perhaps some sort of broadcasting?

```
out = [i.intersection(s) for i in l]
```

**EDIT**

List `l` can be as long as 1000 elements long.

My end objective is to create a matrix which has the length of elements of the pairwise intersection of elements of `l`. So `s` is an element of `l`.

```
out_matrix = list()
for s in l:
    out_matrix.append([len(i.intersection(s)) for i in l])
```

Comment: *premature optimization is evil* How big is `l` that you are concerned about performance? `x in y` when `y` is a set is O(1), so you currently have an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought when reading this question was "sure, use `numpy`". Then I decided to do some tests:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer

s = {1, 2, 3, 4}
l = [{1}, {1, 2, 3}, {3}] * 1000  # 3000 elements
arr = np.array(l)


def list_comp():
    [i.intersection(s) for i in l]


def numpy_arr():
    arr & s

print(min(Timer(list_comp).repeat(500, 500)))
print(min(Timer(numpy_arr).repeat(500, 500)))
```

This outputs

```
# 0.05513364499999995
# 0.035647999999999236
```

So `numpy` is indeed a bit faster. Does it really worth it? not sure. A `~0.02` seconds difference for a 3000 elements list is neglectable (especially if considering the fact that my test didn't even take into account the time it took to create `arr`).

Keep in mind that even when using `numpy` we are still in the grounds of O(n). The difference is due to the fact that `numpy` pushes the `for` loop down to the C level, which is inherently faster than a Python `for` loop.